# What kind of SPSS test is this?

Tags: anova, spss

I was wondering if anyone could tell me what kind of SPSS test would output something like this? I am trying to determine what method they used to compare whether nursing intervention or nicotine patch reduced the number of cigarettes a patient smoked daily compared to no treatment/intervention. I want to be able to recreate this output somehow. Please let me know. thanks.

[image]

Comment: So are you saying you saw this somewhere & are wondering what they did? Where did you see it? If it was in a article, there should have been a description of their analyses.

Comment: This is a standard ANOVA: you can confirm that by reproducing the $F$ statistic and its p-value from the `N` and `Mean (SD)` columns.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this output table was created in SPSS, as the basic formatting is very different to SPSS. As whuber has said, it is a completely standard ANOVA. There are quite a few ways of getting something like this from SPSS, but the easiest would be to select **Analyze > Compare Means > One-Way ANOVA**, and selecting a **Post Hoc** comparison. I can't tell from this output what specific post hoc comparison was performed based on the data provide; however, most academic fields have their own preferred "standard" approach (e.g., Tukey, or, if standard are very low, LSD).

The output suggests that Nurse counselling was better than no Treatment (p = 0.036). Due to the small sample sizes, there is not really enough power to conclude much about Nicotine patch in my opinion.